# Is there a way to exclude a certain file pattern in Apache Beam

Tags: apache-beam

Is there a way to disallow a certain pattern, which will be provided to the Apache Beam's pipeline?
For instance, I want to open all folders that start with "Do" (it'd be like this: Do*), but I'd also want to exclude a word "Docker".
Does Apache Beam have smth to help to implement that?
Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I guess you can do it only by filtering the results of the output of either `FileIO.match()` or `FileIO.matchAll()` manually. Not sure if it's possible to do with a current FileIO API.